# Validating dynamic radio button group

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to validate the values of a radio button group in php. 
The radio buttons are dynamically created in the form. 
I can validate the radio button if it is only one radio group, for example.

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
</form>
```

this is for passing values of radio button

```
if(isset($_POST['radio1']))
{
    *some codes
}
```

Since the radio buttons in my form are dynamically created, the names of the radio groups increment like radio1, radio2, radio3 so on. 
How can I make validation for this dynamic radio button group?

Comment: Try same client side scripting....

Comment: I'm sorry but I need a server side validation, Is it not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Better create radio button with name as array. Like

```
<form method="post">
<input type="radio" name="radio[1]">
<input type="radio" name="radio[2]">
</form>
```

and server side you can check with a foreach

```
foreach($_POST['radio'] as $key=>$radio){
   if($radio == "on"){
      echo "$key is checked";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my name value is something like this, radio1, radio2, radio3, 
not that radio[1], radio[2],

Comment: is it the same method? hmmm

Comment: since it is placed in a [], they became 1 array, so the problem is that, It cannot validate which one is null, that why I made radio1, radio2, radio3, not radio[1] so on..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form>
<input type="radio" class="rdo" name="radio[]">
<input type="radio" class="rdo" name="radio[]">
            .....
<input type="radio" class="rdo" name="radio[]">//n value
</form>

var arr = new Array();
    $('.rdo:checked').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
```

In server side

```
$i=0;

  if(count($_POST['radio'])==0){
  return false;
  }
    foreach($_POST['radio'] AS $rs){
      if($rs!=''){
            //Some code
      }
      else{
         $i++;
      } 
    }
    if($i==count($_POST['radio'])){
      return false;
    }else{
      //some code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using radio elements as array like below:

```
 <form method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="radio[0]" value="0.1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio[0]" value="0.2">
    <input type="radio" name="radio[1]" value="1.1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio[1]" value="1.2">
    <input type="submit" name="s" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and from server try

```
  if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
    echo "<pr>";
    print_r($_POST);    
  }
```

Comment: When the other radio isset, for example, radio[0]-choosen radio[0],,,radio[1],radio[1]--not choosen, it does not read the null value.. hmm